# ERROR: NotFoundError - Elastic Beanstalk can't find a platform version that matches "python-3.9"

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy Django project, but I am finding the below error
ERROR: NotFoundError - Elastic Beanstalk can't find a platform version that matches "python-3.9"
I am using python version 3.9, any suggestions will be highly appreciated

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.python

Comment: You'll either need to downgrade your application to Python 3.8, or switch to a Docker based deployment.